# How to convert a row from Dataframe to String

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe which contains only one row with the column name: `source_column` in the below format:

```
forecast_id:bigInt|period:numeric|name:char(50)|location:char(50)
```

I want to retrieve this value into a String and then split it on the regex `|`
First I tried converting the row from the DataFrame into the String by following way so that I can check if the row is converted to String:

```
val sourceColDataTypes = sourceCols.select("source_columns").rdd.map(x => x.toString()).collect()
```

When I try to print: `println(sourceColDataTypes)` to check the content, I see `[Ljava.lang.String;@19bbb216` 
I couldn't understand the mistake here. Could anyone let me know how can I properly fetch a row from a dataframe and convert it to String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try this:

```
df.show()

//Input data
//+-----------+----------+--------+--------+
//|forecast_id|period    |name    |location|
//+-----------+----------+--------+--------+
//|1000       |period1000|name1000|loc1000 |
//+-----------+----------+--------+--------+

df.map(_.mkString(",")).show(false)

//Output:
//+--------------------------------+
//|value                           |
//+--------------------------------+
//|1000,period1000,name1000,loc1000|
//+--------------------------------+        

df.rdd.map(_.mkString(",")).collect.foreach(println)

//1000,period1000,name1000,loc1000
```

Comment: I am passing this expression to a val and printing as:
val sourceColDataTypes = sourceCols.rdd.map(_.mkString(",")).collect.foreach(println)
    println("source columns: ")
    println(sourceColDataTypes)
O/P comes out as: source columns:
()
I see that the foreach giving the actual output but the val: sourceColDataTypes  doesn't result in anything.

Comment: 1. I am getting a column value from a RDBMS table which has column details to create a Hive table:
val sourceCols = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", hiveMetaConURL)
.option("dbtable", "(select source_columns from base.coltables where tablename='base.forecast') as sCols")
.option("user", metaUserName)
.option("password", metaPassword)
.load()
2. The data is separated by "|". I want to convert this a String, replace "|" with comma and created a DDL using the same String. For that, Im trying to convert the value present on the DF to a String.

Comment: If you have assigned this `sourceCols.rdd.map(_.mkString(","))` to `sourceColDataTypes` then it wouldn't work as it's an RDD. You need to use 
`collect` to change it to a collection and use `foreach` to print it out.

Comment: I have used it with collect. I have given what I tried in the first comment.

Comment: This is the output:
source columns:
[Ljava.lang.String;@236206f8

Comment: It's a collection use sourceColDataTypes.foreach(println)